# Getting Regionserver throwing InvalidToken exception in logs

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I have noticed following error in my region server logs:

```
org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: access control error while attempting to set up short-circuit access to /apps/hbase/data/data/default/my-table/eb512b4b9f9fa9cb2a1a3930d9c9f18b/r/df1694a4542f419992f86b219541fb6fBlock token with block_token_identifier (expiryDate=1519482398334, keyId=1283446178, userId=hbase, blockPoolId=BP-1872413417-101.33.253.88-1458393583173, blockId=1133036852, access modes=[READ]) is expired.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.requestFileDescriptors(BlockReaderFactory.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.createShortCircuitReplicaInfo(BlockReaderFactory.java:490)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.shortcircuit.ShortCircuitCache.create(ShortCircuitCache.java:782)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.shortcircuit.ShortCircuitCache.fetchOrCreate(ShortCircuitCache.java:716)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.getBlockReaderLocal(BlockReaderFactory.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.BlockReaderFactory.build(BlockReaderFactory.java:333)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.actualGetFromOneDataNode(DFSInputStream.java:1118)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.fetchBlockByteRange(DFSInputStream.java:1056)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.pread(DFSInputStream.java:1411)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSInputStream.read(DFSInputStream.java:1374)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataInputStream.read(FSDataInputStream.java:89)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$AbstractFSReader.readAtOffset(HFileBlock.java:1380)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderImpl.readBlockDataInternal(HFileBlock.java:1591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlock$FSReaderImpl.readBlockData(HFileBlock.java:1470)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2.readBlock(HFileReaderV2.java:437)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileBlockIndex$BlockIndexReader.loadDataBlockWithScanInfo(HFileBlockIndex.java:259)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2$AbstractScannerV2.seekTo(HFileReaderV2.java:634)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.hfile.HFileReaderV2$AbstractScannerV2.seekTo(HFileReaderV2.java:584)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seekAtOrAfter(StoreFileScanner.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreFileScanner.seek(StoreFileScanner.java:156)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreScanner.seekScanners(StoreScanner.java:363)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.StoreScanner.<init>(StoreScanner.java:217)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HStore.getScanner(HStore.java:2003)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion$RegionScannerImpl.<init>(HRegion.java:5338)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.instantiateRegionScanner(HRegion.java:2494)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getScanner(HRegion.java:2480)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.getScanner(HRegion.java:2462)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.get(HRegion.java:6527)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.get(HRegion.java:6506)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.doNonAtomicRegionMutation(RSRpcServices.java:579)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.multi(RSRpcServices.java:2031)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2114)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:101)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:130)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:107)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-02-24 20:03:10,947 INFO  [RW.default.readRpcServer.handler=151,queue=38,port=16020] hdfs.DFSClient: Access token was invalid when connecting to /101.32.65.239:50010 : org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: access control error while attempting to set up short-circuit access to /apps/hbase/data/data/default/my-table/eb512b4b9f9fa9cb2a1a3930d9c9f18b/r/df1694a4542f419992f86b219541fb6fBlock token with block_token_identifier (expiryDate=1519482398334, keyId=1283446178, userId=hbase, blockPoolId=BP-1872413417-101.33.253.88-1458393583173, blockId=1133036852, access modes=[READ]) is expired.
```

I see [config](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/ShortCircuitLocalReads.html) related to these are already [tweaked](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/admin_hdfs_short_circuit_reads.html) by us.

dfs.client.read.shortcircuit.streams.cache.expiry.ms
300000
hdfs-default.xml

dfs.client.read.shortcircuit.streams.cache.size
4096
hdfs-site.xml

I also see a [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-9803?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels) raised by [Nick Dimiduk-2](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/HDFS-short-circuit-tokens-expiring-td4251898.html) already facing this, which is still open and in the comments have the config suggested by a user facing same issue, which we are also using,

Anyone faced this issue or knows about it and have any resolution/suggestion for this?